# How to create a single npm package for common libraries to be used across different projects?

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend, package.json

There are several projects that use the same react ecosystem libraries (react, react-dom, react-router, react-redux etc). Currently each project maintains the versions of these libs individually. I want to create an npm package (eg: 'ly-react'), which would contain all these different libraries as dependencies. And then in every project I can just install `ly-react` and call other libs would automatically get included and I can use them as normal.

My questions are :

1. How to actually do this?
2. If `ly-react` has 5 libs that it includes and project only uses 3, would all 5 be included in the production build or just the ones being used? I do not know how this works, I would appreciate if someone can explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Since you'll be including also a lot of other configuration (eslint, testing, npm scripts...), you'd better haver directly a template repo to clone maybe ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can create an npm account and publish the package on npm. You can make the package unscoped, scoped, or private based on your use-case.
For more information, you can check: https://docs.npmjs.com/packages-and-modules/contributing-packages-to-the-registry